# Insert and update in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table

```
table1
****************************
id | start_date | end_date  
1    30/06/2012   01/01/9999
```

When I insert a new row

```
id | start_date | end_date
1    30/06/2012   26/06/2012 <- Now it is the start date of the next row2
2    26/06/2012   01/01/9999
```

The start date of insert row will became the end date of previous row  and so on.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    table1(cate_id,task_id,obj,end_date,start_date,line)
                    SELECT 
                        $cate_id ,
                        $task_id,
                        $obj,
                        '2011-02-28', -> this what I am trying to do
                        '9999-01-01', -> this what I am trying to do
                        line1 
                    FROM 
                        line_task
                    WHERE 
                         line_task_id = (
                                            SELECT 
                                                line_task_id 
                                            FROM 
                                                task 
                                            WHERE 
                                                task_id = 2
                                           )";
```

When I tried something like this:

```
insert into table1(cate_id,task_id,obj, start_date, end_date,line) 
values (4,3,23, (Select max(end_date) from table1),end_date,'value_line');
```

I got message :

```
  Error code 1093, SQL state HY000: You can't specify target table 'table1' for update     in FROM clause
Line 1, column 1
```

Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred

Could told me how can I do this with mysql? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
  Set @max_date = Select max(end_date) from table;

    Insert into table(id, start_date, end_date) values (id, @max_date ,end_date);
```

Comment: Error code 1093, SQL state HY000: You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Break this in two queries, 1 to get the max and the next to insert

Answer (score 1):

First,Get the last record end_date :

```
$sql = mysql_query("Select * from table1 ORDER BY ID Desc");

    if ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $end_date=$row['end_date'];
    }
```

then insert the new record with the previous $end_date.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one query

```
INSERT INTO table1(cate_id,task_id,obj, start_date, end_date,line) 
SELECT 4,3,23, MAX(end_date), end_date, 'value_line'
FROM table1;
```

Just have to follow proper syntax (second example): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html